# How do I make CircleCI [1.0] ignore a particular branch?

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci, continuous-delivery

I have many development branches, but I want CircleCI to **only care about master**.

[image]

Is there something I can configure, either in Circle or `circle.yml`? Alas I can't find anything on the topic in Circle's docs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Give CircleCI a list of branches that are the only ones it should auto-build by adding the following to `circle.yml`:

```
general:
  branches:
    only:
      - master
```

Alternatively, if you had a fixed list of branches that you *didn't* want to build, you could blacklist them with `ignore:`

```
general:
  branches:
    ignore:
      - before-rethinkdb
      - rethinkdb
```

Documentation is here: https://circleci.com/docs/configuration/#branches

Comment: Same in case of CircleCI 2.0 ?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not using it at the moment so I can't verify. Sounds like a new question.